# material-ui table not displaying data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I'm trying some stuff with material-ui and I'm having problems with displaying my data from my react-context. What I wanna do is display my context (which is an array) in a material-ui table. It's not a problem with the context because when I print out the array there are elements inside with values. So it has to be an issue with the material table classes. If anyone is familiar with these I would appreciate any help.

This is my component for the table. I'm using the `map()` function to go through my array twice. Once to test at the top of the return-statement, which worked, and then in the material-ui components which didn't work (didnt display any data).

```
export default function PhaseList() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const [phases, setPhases] = useContext(PhasesContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('retrieving phases', phases);
    }, [phases]);

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {phases.map((phase) =>
                    <li key={phase.id}>
                        {JSON.stringify(phase)}
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table className={classes.table} size='small'>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>phase</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>time</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>description;</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {phases.map((phase) => (
                            <TableRow key={phase.id}>
                                <TableCell component='th' scope='phase'>
                                    {phase.name}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.time}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.description}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>

        </>
    );
}
```

There's no error or anything, when i click the button to add it, it just creates an empty row
as you can see here.The elements with the values are printed on top, but not in the table.
The only thing in the console I'm getting is this warning: *Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.*
[image]

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has got to do with your data structure.

```
{phases.map((phase) => (
                            <TableRow key={phase.phase.id}>
                                <TableCell component='th' scope='phase'>
                                    {phase.phase.name}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.phase.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.phase.time}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.phase.description}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
```

You need to change `phase.name` to `phase.phase.name`

Now you figure out, you may want to edit your data structure.

Comment: That was it. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not returning anything from the .map function.

Try this one:

```
export default function PhaseList() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const [phases, setPhases] = useContext(PhasesContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('retrieving phases', phases);
    }, [phases]);

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {phases.map((phase) =>
                    return(<li key={phase.id}>
                        {JSON.stringify(phase)}
                    </li>)
                )}
            </ul>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table className={classes.table} size='small'>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>phase</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>time</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>description;</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {phases.map((phase) => (
                            return(<TableRow key={phase.id}>
                                <TableCell component='th' scope='phase'>
                                    {phase.name}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.time}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{phase.description}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>)
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>

        </>
    );
}
```

Here's a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the .map function

Comment: `map` function returns the value implicitly we don't have to mention it explicitly. Both `arr.map(o=>{return o*2})` and `arr.map(o=>o*2)` are the same. And your answer will give error at the `return` statement as `return` must be within a block `{}`.

Comment: the map function uses round brackets  () so you don't need to return.